# Ho to create a new filter task in camunda

Tags: camunda, formsflow.ai

I am using the latest version of forms-flow-ai, I need to implement filter task based on users or user groups. How to implement that using camunda and implement that in forms-flow-web

[image: enter image desc]

Answer (score 3):

U can create the filters in camunda. I will give a sample example of how to configure the filter for the reviewer group please refer to the following screenshots.

Step 1 Login to camunda and go to task list page => create filter
[image: step 1]

step 2 Add your filter
[image: step 2]

step 3 Add criteria
[image: step 3]

step 4 Add permission
[image: step 4]